# 2点間を結ぶ3D放物線の中間地点のZ軸のみ動かしたい

Tags: unity3d

2点間を結ぶ3D放物線を描画しております。

```
Vector3 _controlPoint = new Vector3( 0, 0, -50 );
var control = (_trans1.position + _trans2.position) / 2 + _controlPoint;
var totalPoints = _middlePoints + 2;
List<Vector3> l_list = new List<Vector3>();
l_list.Add( _trans1.position );
for (int i = 1; i <= _middlePoints; i++)
{
    var t = (float)i / (float)(totalPoints - 1);
    Vector3 _pos1 = Vector3.Lerp(_trans1.position, control, t);
    // Interpolate along line S1: S1 = end - control;
    Vector3 _pos2 = Vector3.Lerp(control, _trans2.position, t);
    // Interpolate along line S2: Q1 - Q0
    Vector3 _pos = Vector3.Lerp(Q0, Q1, t);
    l_list.Add( mpos);
}
l_list.Add( _trans2.position );
```

中間地点「control」をセンターからズラそう値を変えているのですが、
地面に対して90°の線ではなく、傾いた線になってしまいます。

```
var control = (_trans1.position + _trans2.position) * 0.85f + _controlPoint;
```

目指しているのは釣り竿のような線を想定しております。
こちらコードでどこを修正すればよろしいでしょうか

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: あげられているコードでは 変数 Q0, Q1, mpos が定義されていません。問題文コードの修正をおすすめします。

Answer (score 0):

`control`の計算方法が間違っています。次のようにすれば正しい中間点が求まると思います。

```cs
var control = Vector3.Lerp(_trans1.position, _trans2.position, 0.85f) + _controlPoint;
```